# PayPal sandbox transaction success even if payer account has 0.00 balance

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I currently set up this plugin on my reactjs script and everything working fine.

But I've noticed that even when personal account with 0.00 with no balance I could also proceed and finish normal payment ...

Is this my problem or this is just in sandbox?

```
  <PayPalButton
  createOrder={(data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: price
        }
      }],
      application_context: {
        shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING" 
      }
    });
  }}
  onApprove={(data, actions) => {
    
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
      alert('succes');
    });

  }}
  catchError={(err) => {
    alert(err)
  }}
  onError=((err) => {
    alert(err)
  }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

The paying account needs a funding source to pay. When you create a sandbox account it will usually have a card and bank associated with it by default, both of which have unlimited funds.

Unfortunately this unlimited money is only available in sandbox mode

Comment: Thanks for reply, so my code is totally fine? Just when i go live there will no be problems or bugs? I would not like users to use a bug in the system

Comment: You do not need a balance to pay when there are other funding sources. It is working as designed and intended, there is no bug.